# How can I get all list of g.doubleclick.net?

Tags: domain, google

I'd like to list these doubleclick domains.

I found

1. googleads.g.doubleclick.net
2. adclick.g.doubleclick.net

Does anyone who can make list?

Comment: I'm sure doubleclick could.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no legitimate way of compiling a list of subdomains without the cooperation of the domain's owner.  If you did happen to have her cooperation, it would be possible to do a zone transfer on the domain with an AXFR query like so:

```
dig @ns1.google.com g.doubleclick.net axfr
```

I, however, do not have permission for a zone transfer, so I receive an error when I attempt as much:

> ; <<>> DiG 9.7.1-P2 <<>> @ns4.google.com g.doubleclick.net axfr
>   ; (1 server found)
>   ;; global options: +cmd
>   ; Transfer failed.

This is the mark of a properly-configured DNS server, so it's not something to hope for in the general case.

Your only other option is a brute-force search of subdomains.  Of course this option is not only rude, it's also not likely to yield great results when subdomains have large names like 'googleads'.